# CSS: set width exact equal to content

Tags: html, css

I am searching for a way, to make a div as width as its biggest child.

Situation:

```
<container>
  <div1></div1>
  <inner_container>
    <item1>
    <item2>
    <item3>
    ...
  </inner_container>
</container>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hmman06s/1/

**Note:**

```
item width is fix (using background image)
item margin is fix
container width is in %
```

Now i want, that div1 is as width, as the line of items of `inner_container`.
Like in this image:

[image]

But using `inline-block`, depending on screen width, i get something like this:
See the green extra space:

[image]

Is the a css-only way, to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Share your code. Or better, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then ask a correct question.

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires JavaScript.

Comment: Just change your max-width to 78% and it looks fine.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude i posted a link to jsfiddle (see under my situation description). This is a minimal runable code, representing my problem.

Comment: @ChrisG That does not solve the problem, depending on screen size, it needs other width.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the effect you are after, using CSS `@media` queries.

If your `container` is `24px` less wide than the `viewport` width and the `inner_container` is `120px` less wide than the `container`, then the `inner_container` will always be `144px` less wide than the `viewport`.

If your item is `80px` wide and has a margin either side of `10px`, then you will only want the `inner_container` to expand, every time its inner width reaches a multiple of `100px`.

If we add in padding of `12px` to the left and the right of the row of items (making the `inner_container` another `24px` wider), we now have enough information to calculate all the `viewport` breakpoints:

1. **Ten items** requires a viewport of **1168px** *(10 x 100px + 24px + 144px)*
2. **Nine items** requires a viewport of **1068px** *(9 x 100px + 24px + 144px)*
3. **Eight items** requires a viewport of **968px** *(8 x 100px + 24px + 144px)*
4. **Seven items** requires a viewport of **868px** *(7 x 100px + 24px + 144px)*
5. **Six items** requires a viewport of **768px** *(6 x 100px + 24px + 144px)*
6. **Five items** requires a viewport of **668px** *(5 x 100px + 24px + 144px)*

Consequently:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1267px) {  /* 10 items */
inner-container {width: 1024px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1167px) {  /* 9 items */
inner-container {width: 924px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1067px) {  /* 8 items */
inner-container {width: 824px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 967px) {  /* 7 items */
inner-container {width: 724px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 867px) {  /* 6 items */
inner-container {width: 624px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {  /* 5 items */
inner-container {width: 524px;}
}
```

Comment: hmm, ok, thank you.
I thought, there is an easy way to do it, but if not, i will use js for this.

Comment: It's the only way I can think of for a div to have a series of fixed-widths, which don't otherwise expand or contract between breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help to you. in your style change these widths

```
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: grey;
  width:100%;
}

.item {
  width:9%;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left:0.09%;
  background-color: red;

}
```

**NOTE: it is simple logic, what you have to do is 
`item-width= full-width/number_of_items_you_want` in your case `item_width = 100/11`**

Comment: the amount of items per line depends on screen width. And item width is fix because i use a background image

Comment: no it does not depent on screen width.what you have to do is give 100% width to your container and devide it the nuber of items that you decide to put that is it.we use `%` mark to give width,so it automatically change according to the width when you resize.so you don't want to bother about it.I have updated the `margin-left:0.09%` change it in you answer.try with resizing your browser(with mobile).

Comment: the page im working on, is not for mobile devices, so the screen width will vary very strong. If i would set a fixed number of items per line it looks good on some devices and bad on all other. So i need to keep the amoung of items per line variable.